# When I get a recall, prescription for a decision tree in python. How do I get these two when class=0 and class=1 separately?

Tags: python, decision-tree

I know how to get two of them together when class=0 and class=1, but I don't know how to get them separately...
please help

Here is my code

```
`Xtr, Xts, Ytr, Yts = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, shuffle  =True, random_state=85)

t1 = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth = 5, min_samples_split = 50, min_samples_leaf = 25)
t1.fit(Xtr, Ytr)

y_pred = t1.predict(Xts)`
```

Comment: Hello, I don't understand your question. Can you explain it better and show your desired output?